# AS2: Checking if a MovieClip has any graphics rendered

Tags: flash, rendering, actionscript-2

I'm working on a SmartVersioning ad using MediaMind using ActionScript 2 (the publisher doesn't allow AS3).

Skipping over how it's implemented - basically what I have is a collection of MovieClips on the **main timeline** that contain a swappable image (through the Smart Versioning service). You can only define objects as Smart Versioning objects if they are on the main timeline.

What I'm doing with this is using BitmapData to use the assets on the main timeline as a source for the graphics throughout the animation.

Should be as easy as:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(143, 230, true, 0);

bmd.draw(_root.person1);
attachBitmap(bmd, getNextHighestDepth());
```

However there's a delay in loading Smart Versioning assets (ie the images needed throughout the animation) - so this can cause the above code to fail if the asset hasn't loaded in time.

I then went on to amend my above code to:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(143, 230, true, 0);

onEnterFrame = function():Void
{
    bmd.draw(_root.person1);
}

attachBitmap(bmd, getNextHighestDepth());
```

Works, but has obvious problems and is pretty poor coding. So, is there a way to do a check to see if any graphics have been drawn into the MovieClip this code is run within? Something like:

```
onEnterFrame = function():Void
{
    if(<hasNoGraphicsYet>)
        bmd.draw(_root.person1);
    else
        delete(onEnterFrame);
}
```

Comment: What's about checking `height` and `width` of the `MovieClip`. Shouldn't the are `0` if nothing is drawn?

Comment: Ah perfect.. If you wanna post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that using those enterFrame checks is bad coding.  Why not use the COMPLETE event from the SmartVersioning component to determine when your asset XML is loaded?

C&P from mediamind:

```
// wait until all of the Smart Items have been loaded
stop();
import eyeblaster.events.EBSmartVersioningEvent;
// Register to the XML_LOADED event in order to update the Smart Items
SVComp.addEventListener(EBSmartVersioningEvent.XML_LOADED,onXMLloaded);
// Register to the COMPLETE event in order to continue movie playback after all items are updated
SVComp.addEventListener(EBSmartVersioningEvent.COMPLETE,onComplete);

function onXMLloaded(event)
{
    // update all Smart Items
    SVComp.updateAllItems();
}
function onComplete(event)
{
    // check that the Complete event is for all items
    if (event.item==null)
    {
        play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! However I'm locked into using AS2 so that won't work for me in this case. Kept on file for future ads though :)

Comment: This is AS2, from the AS2 Eyeblaster API reference.  If you have an account then you should be able to access this link: https://platform.mediamind.com/OnlineHelp/MediaMind/External/#8152

Comment: I've decided this answer is better suited.

Comment: @Marty Wallace You are right, that the answer better suits to your problem, but not to the question title `AS2: Checking if a MovieClip has any graphics rendered` ;-) May be you should change the title, because searches to a similar topic would not be answered by the accepted answer.

Comment: I went to do that and realized I had to change all the body content too and I decided I was too lazy..

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `width` and `height` of the `MovieClip` They should be `0` if nothing is drawn on it.